# Not able to remove checbox after Uncheck event JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code for the adding the checkbox into a new div called "locCounty". But the else does not seem to know what to remove.

```
    //Update Current Filters by COUNTY - STARTS   
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        var tmp = [];
        var checked = [];
        $("#selCounty").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
            var checked = $(this).attr('id');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                tmp.push(checked);
                console.log(tmp);
                $("#locCounty").append('<p id="remove" style="display:inline; float:left"><span id= ' + checked + '>' + checked + '<input type="button" value="X"></input></span></p>');

                $(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
                    $('span', this).remove();
                });
            }
            else {

                $("#locCounty span #"+checked + " input").hide();
                console.log("#"+checked);
                //$("#campaign-name-" + id).remove();
            }
        });
    });
    //Update Current Filters by COUNTY - Ends
```

Comment: What does `console.log("#"+checked);` log to the console?  What is the value of `"#locCounty span #"+checked + " input"` and what is the target HTML markup?

Comment: Note you can't repeat id's in a page as you are doing with `#remove` and there is no such closing tag `</input>`